# How to filter a matrix based on another column

Tags: linux, bash, matrix, awk

I want to filter a matrix file using a column from another file.

I have 2 tab-separated files. One includes a matrix. I want to filter my matrix file based on the first column of FileB. If the headers(column names) of this matrix file (FileA) are present in the first column of File B, I want to filter them to use in a new file. All solutions I could try were based on filtering rows, not fields. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**FileA**

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
R1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
R2 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
R3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
R4 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
R5 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

**FileB**

```
A Green
B Purple
K Blue
L Blue
Z Green
M Purple
N Red
O Red
U Red
```

My expected output is:

**ExpectedOutput**

```
   A B K L M N
R1 0 0 0 0 1 1
R2 1 1 1 0 0 0 
R3 0 0 0 0 0 1
R4 1 1 0 1 0 0
R5 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: That's been asked and answered here several times so you could probably just find it in the archives but [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far so we can help you with that. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I found some R answers but not really a bash solution.

Comment: Bash is a shell. A shell is for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools. While you technically **can** manipulate text in bash or other shells that's not what shells are designed to do and so shell scripts to do so are typically extremely slow, complicated, and hard to write robustly. What you probably actually want is a solution using a standard UNIX tool such as awk (awk being the tool that the guys who invented shells also invented for those shells to call to manipulate text in general). OK, post one of those R solutions and tell us what the problem is with using it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, what the heck, I'm not sure having you post an R script is really going to make any difference other than satisfying my need to be pedantic so here y'go:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    outFldNames2Nrs[$1] = ++numOutFlds
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    $0 = "__" FS $0
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        outFldNr = outFldNames2Nrs[$inFldNr]
        out2inFldNrs[outFldNr] = inFldNr
    }
}
{
    printf "%s", $1
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2inFldNrs[outFldNr]
        if (inFldNr) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $inFldNr
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
__ A B K L M N
R1 0 0 0 0 1 1
R2 1 1 1 0 0 0
R3 0 0 0 0 0 1
R4 1 1 0 1 0 0
R5 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

I'm using the term "field name" to apply to the letter at the top of each column ("field" in awk). Try to figure the rest out for yourself from looking at the man pages and adding "prints" if/when useful and then feel free to ask questions if you have any.

I added `__` at the front of your header line so you'd have the same number of columns in every line of output - that makes it easier to pass along to other tools to manipulate further but it's easy to tweak the code to not do that if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

As @EdMorton mentions, `bash` may not be a suitable tool to manipulate
complex data structure as a table from maintainability and robustness
point of view.
Here is a bash script example just for information:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen
declare -a ary include

while read -r alpha color; do
    seen["$alpha"]=1
done < FileB

while read -r -a ary; do
    if (( $((nr++)) == 0 )); then    # handle header line
        echo -n "  "
        for (( i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++ )); do
            alpha="${ary[$i]}"
            if [[ ${seen["$alpha"]} = 1 ]]; then
                echo -n " $alpha"
                include[$((i+1))]=1
            fi
        done
    else
        echo -n "${ary[0]}"
        for (( i=1; i<${#ary[@]}; i++ )); do
            if [[ ${include[$i]} = 1 ]]; then
                echo -n " ${ary[$i]}"
            fi
        done
    fi
    echo
done < FileA
```

If `python` is your option, you can say instead something like:

```
import pandas as pd

dfb = pd.read_csv("./FileB", sep="\s+", header=None)
vb = [x[0] for x in dfb.values.tolist()]

dfa = pd.read_csv("./FileA", sep="\s+")
va = dfa.columns.tolist()

print(dfa[sorted(set(va) & set(vb))])
```

Output:

```
    A  B  K  L  M  N
R1  0  0  0  0  1  1
R2  1  1  1  0  0  0
R3  0  0  0  0  0  1
R4  1  1  0  1  0  0
R5  0  0  1  0  1  0
```